# Ember.js: When is the value of an `<input/>` field persisted to the corresponding `Controller` value?

Tags: forms, ember.js

UPDATE: forgot to mention that I use Ember in version `1.0.0-rc2`

Given I have the following (very simple) `Ember.View` object:

```
App.AuthenticationLoginFormView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'form',
  classes: ['ajax-form']
}
```

which is used within a `Handlebars` template like this:

```
{{#view App.AuthenticationLoginFormView  }}
  <div class="ajax-form__row">
      <label>
          Account:<br/>
        {{ view Ember.TextField valueBinding="controller.account" }}
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="ajax-form__row">
      <label>
          Username:<br/>
        {{ view Ember.TextField valueBinding="controller.username" }}
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="ajax-form__row">
      <label>
          Password:<br/>
        {{ view Ember.TextField type="password" valueBinding="controller.password" }}
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="ajax-form__row">
      <a href="" class="ajax-form__reset-link" {{action "reset" }} >Reset</a>
      <button class="ajax-form__button" {{action "login" target="controller"}} >Login</button>
  </div>
{{/view }}
```

and a `Controller` for the whole thing which looks like:

```
App.AuthenticationLoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  account: null,
  username: null,
  password: null,

  login: function() {
    // if I call, for example, this.get('account') I get the correct value
  }
});
```

as I've written in the code sample, I get the 'correct' value within the `login` function which is called on form submit. but if I try to interrupt the `transitionTo` action within the corresponding `Route` object, all values of the controller seem to be `null`:

```
App.AuthenticationLoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    reset: function(){
      console.log(this.controller.get('account'); // <-- prints 'null'!
      this.transitionTo('reset');
    }
  }
});
```

is it possible to get the value of the `input` fields even if there was no `action` executed on the controller? if yes, how would I implement it? do I need a listener for each `Ember.TextField` which is fired on a `keyEvent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need a listener on every Ember.TextField, extend it:
extend Ember.TextField and hook into the change event:

```
App.MyTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    change: function() {
        console.log(this.get('value'));
    }
});
```

in your template:

```
{{ view App.MyTextField type="password" valueBinding="controller.password" }}
```

now everytime you type something in the textfield you should see a console output.

hope it helps.

EDIT:

```
App.AuthenticationLoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    reset: function(){
      console.log(this.controllerFor('authenticationLogin').get('password')); // <-- what does this print?
      this.transitionTo('reset');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. so I'm able to hook into this event, but how could I wire it up with my property inside the `Controller` so that I could get the value even if no `<form>` action was triggered?

Comment: in your route to get acces to your controller try something: `this.controllerFor('authenticationLogin').get('password');` and see if you get the value

Comment: I tried it and didn't get any value -- this was the clue! on all the sources I found on the net, it was stated that the `Controller` in an Ember Application is a `Singleton`, but somehow there were always 2 `AuthenticationLoginController` instances present... it seems that it is necessary to tell the `renderTemplate` method of the `Route` explicitly which `Controller` to use... now everything works like a charm with all `Bindings` in place and up & running, so for this issue I won't need to overwrite the `change` property. but it's always good to know what's possible in a framework ;)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution :) The renderTemplate method didn't come to my mind since I was thinking you where using strictly the conventions, and conventionally there would be only one AuthenticationController

Comment: it was my fault as I didn't write the full code into my codesnippet of `AuthenticationLoginRoute`... thanks a lot for your time and knowledge - I'll accept your answer and close this question :)